# jQuery inputmask for hours and minutes

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using Robin Herbots' excellent jQuery inputmask. How do I create a mask to allow a user to enter hours and minutes in the format 99hrs 99mins. I want the input mask to appear like __hrs __mins

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work? Please provide a code sample, preferably a jsfiddle or similar. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks tbrisker - I have answered my own question below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per buried in the documentation, which if one takes the time to read, one would find **Escape Special Mask Characters**

Use : 99\\hr\\s 99\\min\\s

the h, s and m are special characters used by the datetime extension.

Thanks Pawal for reminding me to RTFM ;-)

Comment: what about 12 hours time? e.g. 8:59 am

Answer (score 1):

You should briefly read the documentation of plug-in before using it. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

And now moving forward to your query, i think you want the user to enter only `hrs` and `mins`, while actually the input looks like `__hrs __mins` , So you can do this ,

```
$('#input-field-id').inputmask('99hrs99mins');
```

And here is the demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5dGj/1/) of that.

I hope it helps your cause.

P.S

Before asking question you should abide by these [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pawal. You're right, 99hrs99mins does work as per your jsFiddle. I had tried that. But my mask was appearing as '__r___in_'. Your response has led me to further investigate and I have realised that it is the inclusion of the inputmask.date.extensions that is causing this to go awry. I am using inputmask, inputmask.date.extensions and inputmask.numeric.extensions on the same page as I have a number of fields that require date, numeric and text inputmasks. I am going through the documentation and still investigating. Would you have any other idea? Much appreciated.